# Autofac: Registering types with dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies, autofac

I'm trying to register my WPF views with their corresponding viewmodels and avoid having to use code behind.

So far my code would look like this:

```
 builder.Register(c =>
    {
        PageA page = new PageA();
        page.DataContext = c.Resolve<PageAViewModel>;
        return page;
    });

    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        PageB page = new PageB();
        page.DataContext = c.Resolve<PageBViewModel>;
        return page;
    });
```

Is there are a more dynamic way to avoid having to write these lines for all views/pages? (if possible without using Service locator pattern).

Comment: Thanks Renat. any specific answer you refer to? I generally get my stuff running, but i'm looking for some shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic method that will register your types :

```
public static class RegistrationExtension
{

    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TPage, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> 
        RegisterPage<TPage, TViewModel>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        where TPage : IPage
    {
        return builder.RegisterType<TPage>()
                      .OnActivated(e =>
                      {
                          e.Instance.DataContext = e.Context.Resolve<TViewModel>();
                      });

    }
}
```

and then register your pages like this :

```
builder.RegisterPage<PageA, PageAViewModel>();
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrill. I guessthis is as dynamic is it can get with generics.